# Xcode Code Signin issue

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I created all certificates and provision profiles and include it. But xcode still gives me error.. " Your build settings specify a provisioning profile with UIID " can somebody tell me what correct settings are?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add your device id in provisioning profile, from apple mebership account. Then try, it will work.

Comment: All certificates added and prov files. I found the problem It was expired apple certificate

Answer (score 0):

In provisioning profile Debug and Release select same provisioning profile name. Also check all the certificates you have created some of certificates may expire to. Try creating all certificates freshly. I am not sure my this answer,It may help you . Also you are in confuse with the development and distribution certificates (try to differentiate development and distribution certificate)